# Javascript: Find the previous whitespace from a known location in a string

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble figuring out how to find the previous white space from a know location in a string.

For Example: here is a sql statment and I need to find the tableName when `.*` is used. Finidng the table alias is easy as I can get it from the a.* but I need the actual table name.

```
"select a.*,  a.id , distinct b.id as newID, a.name, test as columnName, b.* from table1name a inner join table2name b on a.id = b.id"
```

So using a bunch of `indexof(" " + tableAlias + " ")` I can figure out where the tablename ends but I do not know the length or the starting position. What I need is to find the whitespace just before the point that my indexof returns.

so indexof in the example above produces `15` when looking for `" " + tableAlias + " "` which identifies the end of the actual table name so I can assume that the tableName ends at index `14` and starts just after the whitespace before 14 (Assuming of course that there is no space in the tablename...

any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf

Comment: I am trying to build a query engine for a cloud based application that allows my to create tables and run queries. Currently I have to create the target table first, then the query and then run the query to populate the table. I would like to write a parser that would do all that work for me for a given query. I already have it working for cases where table Aliasing is not being used but when an alias is used I need the name of the original table so that I can retrieve the columns to build the target table.

Comment: Use `substr()` to get the substring ending at the known location, and `lastIndexOf()` to find the position of the last space in that.

Comment: Yep, lastIndexOf was the ticket. for some reason I thought that produced the final instance of a given string not the previous.

Comment: On another note... If you down voted this can you at least leave a comment as to why? These forums are supposed to be here to help people not discourage them from reaching out which is what you do by being purposefully unhelpful. Thank you to the guys who actually did help

Answer (score 0):

you could just iterate over the string and try to find a whitespace

```
 //      0                           28     35
 var str = "select a, b, distinct c from myTable where a < 5";


 var i = 35;    // position of the end of myTable (you already calculated it)
 for(;i >= 0; i--){
    if(str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        break;
    }
 }

 // now i marks the index of the whitespace before myTable (in the example it would be 28)
```

Comment: That's PHP, not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who contributed here. The string.lastIndex of was the answer. I thought that this function returned the final index of a given string but it turns out that it gives the previous instance so it's exactly what I needed.